# PiGlow not working

Tags: python

After following the steps specified in [Boeeerb's PiGlow github repo](https://github.com/Boeeerb/PiGlow), when I try to run the `test.py` file it gives me the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last) :
   File "test.py" , line 9, in <module>
      piglow = PiGlow()
   File "/home/pi/piglow/piglow.py" , line 30,in _init_
      self.bus = SMBus(i2c_bus)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have tried rebooting, and trying it multiple times. I also used the `ls` command to ensure the file is there. What's wrong there?

Comment: Can you provide line 30 of `piglow.py`? On the github repository it's `self.bus = SMBus(i2c_bus)`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Raspbian? If so, i2c is disabled by default. Let's get it enabled...

Make sure you've got updated packages and have i2c-tools installed. You likely do but just in case...

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install python-smbus i2c-tools
```

All good? Add the i2c modules...

```
echo -e "i2c-bcm2708\ni2c-dev" | sudo tee --append /etc/modules
```

Cool? Now, make sure you remove them from the modprobe blacklist (if you have one)...

```
MPBL=/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf; [ -f ${MPBL} ] && sudo perl -p -i -e 's:(blacklist (spi|i2c)-bcm2708):#$1:g' ${MPBL}
```

Sweet. Finally reboot the Pi...

```
reboot
```

Gold. Try it again. Working ok now? Got my info from here:

http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c

Thank you Lady Ada!! ;-)